# Process Immediately Killed

Tags: linux, arm, elf

I'm trying to reverse an ARM executable. It's for an embedded system, but I don't have any details about the normally targeted environment.

Here's what `file` shows: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI4 version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, stripped

I've tried running it on Linux using qemu and the process immediately terminates with the message "Killed". Running `strace ./executable` returns this:

`execve("./executable", ["./executable"], [/*13 vars */] <unfinished ...>
+++ killed by SIGKILL +++ 
Killed`

I'm using the Debian Wheezy image from here: https://people.debian.org/~aurel32/qemu/armel/

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: `file` doesn't always give the correct output. Try running `readelf -A` to know specifically the version of ARM.

Answer (score 3):

The process may send itself (or it's child processes) the SIGTERM signal as part of an anti-debugging trick. Hunting for that will require you to search for signal-sending APIs like [`kill`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/kill) and how/when they're being used by the application.

A more simple solution, that is not necessarily RE related, could be that the process is killed by the [OOM killer](https://www.memset.com/docs/additional-information/oom-killer/).

To test that, you can run `mesg | egrep -i “killed process”` inside the emulated machine.

If that's the case, you can easily disable it (add `vm.oom-kill = 0` in `/etc/sysctl.conf`).